# "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" Discord Bot with Python on repl.it

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, typeerror, replit

I wanted to create a Discord bot to send a text message on a Discord server containing all the commands when someone types "^help" but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 38, in on_message
    if help in message.content():
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

This is my code:

main.py

```
import bot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run_discord_bot()
```

bot.py

```
import discord
import responses


async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.get_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = '(token)'
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        print(f'{username} said: "{user_message}" ({channel})')
      
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if "^help" in message.content():
          await message.channel.send("text")
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

I am new to Dicsord bot development so I don't know what else to do.

Comment: `message.content` is a string. No need to put parentheses `()` on it. You used that correctly in many other places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting, `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`, is because you're trying to call a string object as if it is a function. Looking at your error, the issue lies in the following line:

```py
if "^help" in message.content():
```

The `message.content` attribute returns a string. However, you are treating it as a function by using parentheses after `message.content`. To fix this error, you should remove the parentheses:

```py
if "^help" in message.content:
```

Here's the updated code:

```py
import discord
import responses


async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.get_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = '(token)'
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        print(f'{username} said: "{user_message}" ({channel})')

        if "^help" in message.content:
            await message.channel.send("text")

    client.run(TOKEN)
```